# Oracle Number datatype value insertion

Tags: java, oracle10g

I am executing the following query, but it is inserting partial value of first field, i.e 95362 instead of 95362-07

Insertion query::

```
INSERT INTO ACCIDENT VALUES(95362-07,'Orthoptic education on visual ergonomics','Orthoptic education on visual ergonomics');
```

Getting values in the table ::

```
95362,Orthoptic education on visual ergonomics,Orthoptic education on visual ergonomics.
```

Table structure:

```
desc accident

Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------
ID                                      NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
ACC_NAME                                VARCHAR2(4000)                                                                                                                                                                                
ACC_DESC                                VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Comment: You should post your `Select` query and your `table` description. Seems like you are passing a subtraction operation instead of a varchar in your first parameter

Comment: the problem is on insertion , it is inserting 95362 instead of 95362-07. datatype is number of that field

Comment: It's doing so because as I said, it seems that you are passing an operation instead of a varchar in the first parameter. But I can only be sure if you post your table description

Comment: sorry, I updated my question with table structure\

Comment: @MohammodHossain Hyhen you have in `95362-07` is not a number,so you need to change your datatype to `varchar2` to store `95362-07`

Comment: You're sure to insert it `95362`? I can not understand. Should be inserted `95355`.

Comment: @turbanoff ,I am getting data from oracle toad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem, your first column is expecting a data type of `Number`

```
desc accident

Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------
ID                                      NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
ACC_NAME                                VARCHAR2(4000)                                                                                                                                                                                
ACC_DESC                                VARCHAR2(4000)
```

And then, when you insert your query, the first parameter is being computed only the NUMBER part of it, which is `95362`.

To store your ID records in the form `XXXXX-XX` you must change your `ID` column to a `VARCHAR2` data type. Otherwise you'll keep getting this result.

I hope it helped. Cheers